# EF 4.1.3 Implenting Rowversion for Concurrency is not working

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, ef-code-first, rowversion, entity-framework-4.3.1

I have got a BaseEntity class which contains a, byte array called stamp, id and state, which every Entity  inherits from I am mapping the stamp to

```
 Property(t => t.Stamp).IsRequired().IsRowVersion();
```

this is set in  BaseEntityConfiguration
which is set like this

```
 public BaseEntityConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T :B aseEntity
```

The mapping is done like this

```
var baseMapConfiguration = new BaseEntityConfiguration<EntityA>();
           modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(baseMapConfiguration);
           var entityAMap = new EntityAMap(baseMapConfiguration);
```

The database has Stamp ROWVERSION NOT NULL; on the Table EntityA 
I have code that handles DbUpdateConcurrencyException but this does not get caught even though the stamps are different
Also there is no where clause on with the Stamp field which I would expected

```
    SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Extent1].[Stamp] AS [Stamp]
FROM [dbo].[EntityA] AS [Extent1]
```

As you seen no where statement I have also tried it from the with a normal mapping set up but still get the same result

**I have found the problem EF is getting the latest Rowversion instead of the passed in one, How can I stop this. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!EntityA.Stamp.Equals(orignal.Stamp))
{
     ctx.Entry(orignal).OriginalValues["Stamp"] = xmlFile.Stamp;
}
```

I was missing these line of codes from the DAL, this is stop EF putting the current stamp as the search criteria.